# Semicolon delimited text field used in email workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2007, email, workflow-variable

unfortunately, I still have some forms on SharePoint 2007. Somehow, a workflow that was created by a previous person disappeared (grew legs and walked away? idk). I am looking to recreate this workflow but cant wrap my head around getting it done, here's the scoop:

I have a form that allows for selection of multiple checkboxes. These checkbox selections are then concatenated (this step isn't required if you dont think its needed, I just couldnt find a way to reference the selected checkboxes directly) into a text field like so:

> XXXXX; YYYY; Selection3; Selection4; Selection5; etc.

I need my SharePoint workflow to look up each of these values (from another list) and find the corresponding emails to each of the values and then place those values (semicolon delimited) into the **To:** box to send the email.

So basically, it has to take `Selection1` and reference the email list to find `Selection1`'s corresponding email and place it into the **To:** box (and do that for every selection/concat them).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't concatenate, work with the individual fields.

1. In the workflow, create a string variable MyVar.
2. Set the value of the variable with the String Builder.
3. Inside the String Builder use the "Add or change Lookup" button to perform the lookup for the first selection field.
4. type a semicolon
5. repeat steps 3 and 4 for all selection fields, but don't add a semicolon after the last field
6. use the MyVar variable in the To box

Comment: Thank you for the answer Teylyn. I will try this solution tomorrow and let you know how it works. Thanks again.

Comment: The String Builder for SharePoint 2007 does not include the "Add or change Lookup" button. It is a simple "Edit Text" popup box with just Ok and Cancel.

Comment: Okay, so i found the String Builder in 2007. I must use the "Store Dynamic String".  Can you clarify what you mean by "perform the lookup for the first selection field." This is a multiple selection checkbox "choice" column. So, the user can check off 5 different values and it is stored in this field once the form is submitted.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have 2007 around anymore.